# Typedef in chisel

Tags: hdl, chisel

Do we have something similar to `typedef` in the chisel?

e.g (hypothetical syntax):

```
typedef UInt(8.W) SHORT;
typedef UInt(64.W) LONG;
```

Thanks

Comment: The so called “Chisel types” (which are used to initialize components such as Wires and Regs) are actually instances of a data type class (such as `UInt`). So you can just use something like `val SHORT = UInt(16.W)`. If the chisel type object is not cloned by the target you can try `def SHORT = UInt(16.W)` (not sure but maybe in some situations even something like `def SHORT = UInt(16.W).cloneType`)